# echo a php variable which is inside a javascript function which is inside a php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This snippet is of jQuery code is inside the php already...How do I access variables inside the jquery code

```
<?php


echo'
    $( "#searchButton" ).click(function() {


    //    location.reload();
    alert(\"$folder\"); //This is causing error
    });'

?>
```

Comment: Try echoing the variable there instead of just printing the string name of the variable?

Comment: @CertainPerformance like how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
echo'
   $( "#searchButton" ).click(function() {
       alert("'.$folder.'");
   });';
?>
```

Comment: It shows this in the alert box <?php echo $folder;?>

Comment: I have just updated my code. Remove the "" quotation on alert

Comment: It gives this error now SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: is it a `.php` file?

Comment: Asking @MrRobot9.

Comment: @SougataBose yup

Comment: `alert("<?php echo $folder; ?>");` would work.

Comment: @SougataBose it directly prints <?php echo $folder;?> in alert box

Comment: Where is your other **PHP** codes?

Comment: @SougataBose Edited the code

Comment: Try - `alert( " ' . $folder .' ");`. (spaces for understanding.)

Comment: @SougataBose it worked!! Thanks!!

Comment: @MrRobot9 I have just updated my code Depends on our Comment . You can mark as work. :)

Comment: @SougataBose `' . $folder .' = $( "#search" ).val();` initializing a variable like this doesnt work though

Answer (score 0):

try this as echo will return a value to the alert.

```
alert(<?php echo $folder ?>);
```

Comment: It gives this error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: The above answer will work for a .js file

Comment: Edited the code